# Tizen Web Application - run on device

Tags: installation, tizen

I´m very knew to tizen and also to wearables, but I developed a standalone Tizen application in the Tizen ide and testet it on the simulator the whole time. Now I want to run ist on my Samsung Gear S2 to make final tests. But I don´t know how.
Used toutorials aren´t very clear and I found nothing in the communities.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been in the same boat, I know the feeling.

So, the tizen IDE debugging is made through WIFI, you should enable WIFI on your Gear S2.
After connecting, check the IP you'll gonna need it.

Then, add the connection on the Tizen IDE, it's the button next to the one you use to launch the emulator manager.
enter the IP address and port. after connection you're good to go.

Check [Gear Development](http://developer.samsung.com/gear) on the topic "Testing Tool" to more info about connecting your device @ [Connecting Gear S2 Overview](http://developer.samsung.com/gear/connecting-gear-s2-overview).

It's not possible (at least I don't know how) to add breakpoints. Yet, on debug a chrome window will open, and you can debug it there using the developer tools such as any regular browser.

This like above about connecting, has screenshots and step by step procedure.

Cheers,

Ricardo

Comment: I found the explanation on the Gear S2, they are talking to use sbd cmd to install the app onto the watch, but it didn't worked. I have the IDE and also the SDK, but if I enter the command

Comment: You can link it directly trough Tizen IDE, just follow the steps I mentioned above. What kind of issues are you having?